# Dialog - Text on one line

Tags: bash

how to automatically display the text in one line?
Example is the two rows, i need 1 line... Than you
[image]

I tried --cr-wrap and --no-collapse 
[dialog(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to specify larger window:

```
dialog  --yesno 'Hello, this is my first dialog program' 20 60
```

You could use `$COLUMN` and `$LINES` for corresponding sizes:

```
dialog  --yesno 'Hello, this is my first dialog program' $((LINES-4)) $((COLUMNS-4))
```

and even for trapping resize of window in a bash script:

```
trap 'COLUMNS=`tput cols` LINES=`tput lines`' WINCH
```